# YT Analytics API: Likes added and Likes removed

Tags: youtube-api

We were previously collecting the "likes added" and "likes removed" metrics in the YouTube Analytics API viewership report on a daily basis but now we are only given "likes", which is the net of the added and removed.

Are there plans to publish the data as separate metrics again in the future? We would find the "likes added" valuable in our own data analysis.